# Jboss config file in not set set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m?

Tags: java, jboss

Jboss config file is not applying jvm arguments:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
```

Jboss server in deploy application then Out of memory:permgen space error throw

Please help how to resolve this error

JBOSS APPLICATION SERVER FILE CONFIGURATION:

### run.conf

Specify options to pass to the Java VM.

```
if [ "x$JAVA_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
   JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=36000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=36000"
fi
```

### run_with_yjp.bat

```
rem JVM memory allocation pool parameters. Modify as appropriate.
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
```

Comment: in which file do you set the JAVA_OPTS parameter?

Comment: C:\jboss-4.2.2.GA\bin\run.conf and 
C:\jboss-4.2.2.GA\bin\run.bat file

Comment: we config your kit java profiler with eclipse then C:\jboss-4.2.2.GA\bin\run_with_yjp.bat set java_opts

Comment: pleas add the content of the files to your question